# Avoid addition of spaces when using colorbox in equations

Tags: equations, color

Colorbox adds some spaces when I use it in equations. E.g. in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{yellow}{${a^2}+b^2=c^2$}
\colorbox{yellow}{$\colorbox{blue}{$a^2$}+b^2=c^2$}

\end{document}
```

the second equation is longer than the first (just taking into account the mathematical symbols). Is there a way to prevent this? Note that I do not mind that the size of the boxes is larger than the enclosed symbols and that the boxes could overlap symbols which are not enclosed if no spaces are added. Note also that I would like to avoid adding negative spaces by hand.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Besides @DavidCarlisle's answer you might also want to have a look at `\mathstrut`, which is useful to ensure that the various boxes are the same size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The padding is `\fboxsep`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\fboxsep0pt

\begin{document}

\colorbox{yellow}{${a^2}+b^2=c^2$}

\colorbox{yellow}{$\colorbox{blue}{$a^2$}+b^2=c^2$}

\end{document}
```

Or perhaps you meant something more like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}



\def\mycolorbox#1#2{\kern-\fboxsep{\colorbox{#1}{#2}\kern-\fboxsep}}

\parskip\baselineskip

\begin{document}


a \mbox{${a^2}+b^2=c^2$} b

a \colorbox{yellow}{${a^2}+b^2=c^2$} b

{\fboxsep0pt a \colorbox{yellow}{$\colorbox{blue}{$a^2$}+b^2=c^2$} b}

a \mycolorbox{yellow}{$\mycolorbox{blue}{$a^2$}+b^2=c^2$} b

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I change the size of the visible box and its size used for the typesetting independently so that I actually get the effect I described above in my first Note ...?

Comment: Oh I thought that was the effect you meant, added a different version to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly different approach to David's answer, which shows alignment with your original equation and some different spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\colorbox{yellow!80}{${a^2}+b^2=c^2$} \par
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\colorbox{orange!50}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{3pt}$\colorbox{blue!30}{$a^2$}+b^2=c^2$}}

\colorbox{yellow!80}{${a^2}+b^2=c^2$} \par
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\colorbox{orange!50}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{3pt}$\colorbox{blue!30}{$a^2$}\hspace*{-\fboxsep}+b^2=c^2$\hspace*{\fboxsep}}}
\end{document}​
```

In both examples, the `\fboxsep` of the outer `\colorbox` is set to `0pt`, letting the coloured `a^2` set the height of the resulting (`yellow!80`) `\colorbox`. The right end is adjusted to correct for the loss of `\fboxsep`.

The default `\fboxsep` is `3pt`. Using whitespace set as `\fboxsep` is better than using `3pt` explicitly.