# Extra space added after equation when it is coloured

Tags: spacing, equations, color

For some reason space is added after my equation when I colour it. This does not happen if the colour is added to text.

Is there a simple way to prevent this from happening, like a global setting (I am not interested in manually adjusting the space with `\vspace{-1cm}`)? Perhaps there is a better way to colour my equation (another package, another command, etc), or in other words, am I doing something wrong?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{equation*}
    a = b + c
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    a - b &= c\\
    a-c & b
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\vline

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{equation*}
\color{blue}    a = b + c
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    a - b &= c\\
    a-c & b
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

For reference, [the closest question I found to this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51415/avoid-addition-of-spaces-when-using-colorbox-in-equations) doesn't seem to solve my problem, ie, adding `\fboxsep0pt` to my preamble did not change the output.

**EDIT**
The comment `With {\color{blue}a = b + c} there is no additional space ...` solves part of the problem, but it doesn't work when using for example `align` (it gives an error):

```
\begin{align*}
{\color{blue}    a - b &= c}\\
    a-c &= b
\end{align*}
```

If I try to fix this using the command twice leaving the & outside, the spacing around `=` is wrong:

```
\begin{align*}
{\color{blue}    a - b} &{\color{blue}= c}\\
    a-c &= b
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Intersting question... Using `\textcolor{blue}{a = b + c}` there is no additional space,

Comment: True, but then it creates problem if used with align. I will add an example to show that.

Comment: Spacing can be fixed via `{\color{blue}{}= c}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill It seems like too many manual corrections/workarounds, but it works. Cheers.

Comment: Playing with @PeterGrill's advice, I find `\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{}a - b &\color{blue}{}= c\    a-c & b
\end{align*}` to work. There were previous posts about `\color{}` adding padding but I can't seem to find them.

Comment: @Vivi: I agree. I remember David Carlisle had commented about `\color` effecting spacing somewhere.

Comment: @hpesoj626: Interesting that in `align` things are ok without the additional grouping, but not in `equation`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes. I can verify that.

Comment: @PeterGrill it puzzles me, too...

Comment: @Vivi Here's the dupe that I answered re `tabularx` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78633/color-lines-tabularx-add-padding. this one was the duped post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31547/color-changes-cell-height-in-tabular

Comment: @Vivi If you are interested you can look at a related question about coloring math symbols http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-to-color-math-symbols. And here is a question from latex-community.org regarding globally setting the color for equations: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2834

Comment: I'm not convinced this has anything to do with `color`. Two math environments should not be placed 'back to back' like this- you should use `gather*`. When you use `gather*`, the spacing is the same in both

Comment: @cmhughes: Yep, adding some text in between the two display mode equations seems to work just fine with the MWE as above.

Comment: @cmhughes I hadn't heard of gather before. I will check it out. I am also happy for this question to be closed given the related questions and the many suggestions given.

Comment: @hpesoj626 Great! I believe this then qualifies my question as a duplicate, so feel free to close this one.

Comment: @cmhughes But gather doesn't provide alignment?! I want the first equation to be independent and not aligned with the set of equations that comes afterwards, which should in turn be aligned with each other. Gather does not allow one to put equation and align inside it, does it?

Comment: @Vivi I won't vote to close this one yet. I think this one merits a definite answer since this deals with a more specific setting. Eventually though, it might get closed. Answering this in the linked post is not within context, I think. Although it was mentioned there that one needs to scope the effect of `\color` inside `{}` .

Comment: how about this: `\begin{gather*}
 \color{blue} a = b + c\\begin{align*}
    a - b &= c\    a-c & b
\end{align*}
\end{gather*}
`

Comment: @cmhughes It seems to mess up with the alignment. I tried with the equations I am typesetting and look at the difference: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1885087/cmhughes.png

Comment: @cmhughes: You shouldn't use `align*` as the inner environment; I didn't even know that this is possible. With `aligned` as the inner environment, everything works nicely, Vivi.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oh. It's an AMS bug, the alignment is not *color safe* . Never noticed that before:-)  In that case you need explicit grouping (use begingroup rather than bgroup or `{` as it's rather less intrusive into math spacing)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{equation*}
    a = b + c
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    a - b &= c\\
    a-c & b
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\vline

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{equation*}
\begingroup\color{blue}    a = b + c\endgroup
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    a - b &= c\\
    a-c & b
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

---

It's actually a bit harsh to call it an *AMS* bug, the same effect is seen with `\[` in LaTeX however rather than grouping each case, this is probably the correct fix (anywhere in the preamble after loading `amsmath`. I'll ping @barbarabeeton

```
\def\foo#1$$#2!!{\def\mathdisplay##1{#1$$\begingroup#2}}
\expandafter\foo\mathdisplay{#1}!!

\long\def\foo#1$$#2!!{\def\endmathdisplay##1{#1\endgroup$$#2}}
\expandafter\foo\endmathdisplay{#1}!!
```

Comment: Aren't `\patchcmd{\mathdisplay}{$$}{$$\begingroup}{}{}` and `\patchcmd{\endmathdisplay}{$$}{\endgroup$$}{}{}` easier? `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

having found david's inquiry about this while cleaning out old files,
i have finally investigated.

while there is indeed extra (unwanted) space when two display environments
are adjacent, and this space increases when color is added, the `amsmath`
display environments are *not* designed to be used in this manner.
all display material between two blocks of text should instead be placed
into a single environment, which can then be subdivided into "subsidiary"
nested environments as appropriate.  (someone mentioned that in a comment,
but it didn't make it into david's answer.)  here is an expanded example
showing the desired outcome in the last column.  (i've changed `blue` to `red` because blue tends to disappear on my screen.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{equation*}
    a = b + c
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    a - b &= c\\
    a-c &= b
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\vline

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{equation*}
\color{red}    a = b + c
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    a - b &= c\\
    a-c & b
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\vline

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{equation*}
\begingroup\color{red}    a = b + c\endgroup
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    a - b &= c\\
    a-c &= b
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\vline

\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{gather*}
\begingroup\color{red}    a = b + c\endgroup\\
\begin{split}
    a - b &= c\\
    a-c &= b
\end{split}
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

so is this a bug in `amsmath`?  if this extra space appears when a "simple"
one-environment instance comes between two text blocks, then it is definitely
a bug.  if there is no extra space in that context, then it's *not* a bug,
since the behavior is what `amsmath` is designed to do.  here's the example
to decide the matter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

start with some text.  make it a rather long line.
\begin{equation*}
    a = b + c
\end{equation*}
some more text.  make this also a rather long line.
\begin{equation*}
\color{red}    a = b + c
\end{equation*}
still more text.  make this also a rather long line.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

no extra space.  thus i interpret the problem as misuse of the environments,
and not a bug.