\setbeamercolor{math text} introduces extra vertical space in beamer
If I set math text in color, beamer introduces an extra space after display math. This looks like a bug, and I am wondering if there is a workaround.
Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass{beamer} 
 
% Setting math text to red introduces extra 
% vertical space after the display equation
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=red} 

\begin{document}  

\begin{frame}{Lorem ipsum}    
    \begin{itemize}            
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
            \[
                x = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
            \]        
        \item Convallis mi ultrices a orci; placerat aliquam felis            
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}  

Here is the output with \setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=red} 

And here is the correct output when commenting \setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=red}

This question is related to Extra space added after equation when it is coloured, but it is not a duplicate. The connection between the two isn't immediately clear because the math coloring in beamer is achieved using the \setbeamercolor{math text} setting, rather than the typical \color{} command from the xcolor package. This initially made it seem like a beamer bug, until @samcarter highlighted the link in her answer.

@user182601 thanks for the feedback. I edited my question and title accordingly.

You could avoid the problem with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91551/36296
\documentclass{beamer} 
 
% Setting math text to blue introduces extra 
% vertical space after the display equation
\setbeamercolor{mymath}{fg=red}

\def\foo#1$$#2!!{\def\mathdisplay##1{#1$$\begingroup\usebeamercolor[fg]{mymath}#2}}
\expandafter\foo\mathdisplay{#1}!!

\long\def\foo#1$$#2!!{\def\endmathdisplay##1{#1\endgroup$$#2}}
\expandafter\foo\endmathdisplay{#1}!!


\begin{document}  

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Lorem ipsum}    
    \begin{itemize}            
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
            \[
                x = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
            \]        
        \item Convallis mi ultrices a orci; placerat aliquam felis            
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}  



Fantastic, this works! And thanks for the link to the related question.

I noted that the spacing bug also disappear in LuaLaTeX when loading \usepackage{luacolor}. I have no idea why.

@divenex Please write a self-answer about the luacolor solution. This might be useful for future users.

I found that with LuaLaTeX, the extra vertical spacing after display math when using colors disappears upon loading the luacolor package. Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass{beamer} 
 
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=red} 
\usepackage{luacolor}

\begin{document}  

\begin{frame}{Lorem ipsum}    
    \begin{itemize}            
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
            \[
                x = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
            \]        
        \item Convallis mi ultrices a orci; placerat aliquam felis            
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}  

And here is the resulting output

