Universal TikZ highlighter for text, display/inline math, without jumps in Beamer overlays
I have created a new simple highlighter function \hl{} because none of the existing solutions met my specific requirements.
Here are my criteria for the function:

It must work seamlessly in both text and math modes.
It should function properly in both display and inline math.
It needs to be overlay-aware in Beamer presentations.
It should not cause any jumps in Beamer overlays.
It should have different default colors for text and math.
It should allow for an optional color parameter.
It should be concise, with no more than about 15 lines of code.

My intention is not to highlight entire paragraphs; a simple box highlighting (\colorbox style) will suffice.
I have successfully created a function that meets almost all these criteria, except for (6), also thanks to a bug fix in the comment by @cgr.
Could anyone help me address the remaining point (6)? The solution is complicated by my need to use \mathpalette or \matchoice to select the correct math mode.
Below is a minimal example for LuaLaTeX. To run it in pdfLaTeX, simply comment out \usepackage{luacolor}, which will introduce a spurious vertical space after the equation:
%!LW recipe=latexmk (lualatex)

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetheme{AnnArbor} 

% I am not using luacolor, but it solves a vertical spacing bug
% after display math https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/731338/103431
\usepackage{luacolor}

\newcommand\xrectangle[2]{        
    [overlay, fill=#1, rounded corners, blend mode=multiply] 
    ($(#2.south west) - (.3em, .3em)$) rectangle ($(#2.north east) + (.3em, .3em)$);}

\newcommand\xmhl[2]{
    \tikz[baseline=(a.base), inner sep=0]
        \node (a) {$#1#2$} \xrectangle{green!30}{a}}
                
\newcommand\xhl[1]{%
    \ifmmode\mathpalette\xmhl{#1}\else%
        \tikz[baseline=(a.base), inner sep=0]
            \node (a) {#1} \xrectangle{yellow}{a}\fi}
 
% Make \hl overlay-aware     
\newcommand<>{\hl}[1]{\alt#2{\xhl{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}  
 
\begin{frame}{Lorem ipsum}    
    \begin{itemize}            
        \item Lorem ipsum \hl<2>{odor amet} consectetuer adipiscing elit
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
            \[
                \hl<2>{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}}
                +\color{red}\sum_k{\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_k}}
                +\hl<2>{\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}}=0
            \]        
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit        
        \item Convallis mi
            $
                \hl<2>{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}}
                +\color{red}\sum_k{\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_k}}
                +\hl<2>{\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}}=0
            $        
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}  

And here is the resulting output
]
I've come across several highlighter questions below, but unfortunately, none of them resolve my issue. They all tend to add extra spacing and shift the text in Beamer overlays. Additionally, they fail to support both text and various math modes.
How to "highlight" text/formulas with tikz?
Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX
highlighting math

comment your line endings to avoid spaces e.g. { newline adds a space. use {% newline.

Fantastic, thank you! Commenting all line endings in \xhl has indeed resolved the offset issue in normal text mode. Now, I just need to address point (6).

The latest version of tikzmark includes a highlighter sublibrary (which started out in one of the questions you link to). I didn't make it beamer aware but that wouldn't be hard to do.

Thanks, @Andrew. I tried using \usetikzmarklibrary{highlighting}, and it works great in the article class. However, when I switch to the beamer class, the highlights vanish without any error messages.

@divenex it's probably related to the order of layers in the shipout. I'll look into it.

@divenex I've partially fixed it. The highlighting over the top of the text now works (using github version), but because beamer places a full rectangle on the page then highlighting under the text needs a different approach than the shipout hooks that I'm current using.

@AndrewStacey Does it work with \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, it does. So the code is now working (it wasn't before). I just need to transfer the hook from the shipout to the beamer template. Which means remembering how beamer templates work! I think they are actually quite a bit like hooks so it shouldn't be difficult. Just a bit more than I want to do right at this precise moment!

https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/issues/19

Thank you for the update @andrew-stacey. I really appreciate your tikzmark library, which is a staple in my presentations. However, I noticed that your highlighter's approach doesn't quite meet my needs, as it doesn't vertically enclose the entire display math mode expression.

@divenex Yes, I thought that might be the case. You can manually change the dimensions but you'd probably have to do a bit by hand. It would be possible to combine it with one of the other tikzmark libraries that puts nodes around every maths box in existence, but that does feel like a bit more work! Nevertheless, it would still be useful if my highlighting worked with beamer!

You only need add one more option arg #1 for color. Such as \newcommand<>{\hl}[2][yellow]{\alt#3{\xhl{#1}{#2}}{#2}}. The rest of the command definitions will change accordingly. This is a working example:
%!LW recipe=latexmk (lualatex)

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetheme{AnnArbor} 

% I am not using luacolor, but it solves a vertical spacing bug
% after display math https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/731338/103431
\usepackage{luacolor}

\newcommand\xrectangle[2]{        
    [overlay, fill=#1, rounded corners, blend mode=multiply] 
    ($(#2.south west) - (.3em, .3em)$) rectangle ($(#2.north east) + (.3em, .3em)$);}

\newcommand\xmhl[3]{
    \tikz[baseline=(a.base), inner sep=0]
        \node (a) {$#2#3$} \xrectangle{#1}{a}}
                
\newcommand\xhl[2]{%
    \ifmmode\mathpalette{\xmhl{#1}}{#2}\else%
        \tikz[baseline=(a.base), inner sep=0]
            \node (a) {#2} \xrectangle{#1}{a}\fi}
 
% Make \hl overlay-aware     
\newcommand<>{\hl}[2][yellow]{\alt#3{\xhl{#1}{#2}}{#2}}

\begin{document}  
 
\begin{frame}{Lorem ipsum}    
    \begin{itemize}            
        \item Lorem ipsum \hl<2>{odor amet} consectetuer adipiscing elit
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
            \[
                \hl<2>[green!30]{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}}
                +\color{red}\sum_k{\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_k}}
                +\hl<2>[green!30]{\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}}=0
            \]        
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit        
        \item Convallis mi
            $
                \hl<2>[red!30]{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}}
                +\color{red}\sum_k{\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_k}}
                +\hl<2>[red!30]{\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}}=0
            $        
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}  


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Edit: To make it worked with two optional args, I think \NewDocumentCommand will help. But I never thought about using this. It seems work. I hope there is no other side effect from this:


Edit2: As suggested by OP, the first argument of the overlay specification is also need to be optional. So if directly use \hl{<some contents>} in the frame, then it will highlight the contents in all the slides in that frame. Yes. The three optional args could be ignored individually. That is the handy feature of using \NewDocumentCommand, because the three optional args are defined with three different delimiters <>,[] and (). I intended to do this for two color options. But I forgot the overlay specification also could be ignored in your original approach. That's why I didn't use D<>{1-} instead of r<>. I think right now it satisfy all of your requirements. Feel free to accept this answer if it solve your problems.

The \hl command have following syntax right now, the first of all args are all optional:
\hl<(overlay specification)>[<color for text>](<color for math>){<the contents>}
%!LW recipe=latexmk (lualatex)

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetheme{AnnArbor} 

% I am not using luacolor, but it solves a vertical spacing bug
% after display math https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/731338/103431
\usepackage{luacolor}

\newcommand\xrectangle[2]{        
    [overlay, fill=#1, rounded corners, blend mode=multiply] 
    ($(#2.south west) - (.3em, .3em)$) rectangle ($(#2.north east) + (.3em, .3em)$);}

\newcommand\xmhl[3]{
    \tikz[baseline=(a.base), inner sep=0]
        \node (a) {$#2#3$} \xrectangle{#1}{a}}
                
\newcommand\xhl[3]{%
    \ifmmode\mathpalette{\xmhl{#2}}{#3}\else%
        \tikz[baseline=(a.base), inner sep=0]
            \node (a) {#3} \xrectangle{#1}{a}\fi}
 
% Make \hl overlay-aware     
\NewDocumentCommand{\hl}{D<>{1-} O{yellow} D(){green!30} m}{\alt<#1>{\xhl{#2}{#3}{#4}}{#4}}%


\begin{document}  
 
\begin{frame}{Lorem ipsum}    
    \begin{itemize}            
        \item Lorem ipsum \hl<2>[red!30]{odor amet} consectetuer adipiscing elit
        \item Lorem ipsum \hl<2>{odor amet} consectetuer adipiscing elit
            \[
                \hl<2>(blue!30){\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}}
                +\color{red}\sum_k{\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_k}}
                +\hl<2>[green!30](yellow!30){\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}}=0
            \]        
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit        
        \item Convallis mi
            $
                \hl<2>{\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}}
                +\color{red}\sum_k{\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_k}}
                +\hl<2>{\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}}=0
            $        
        \item Lorem ipsum odor amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}  



Thank you very much, @Tom. This is very close to what I need, but it doesn't fulfill criterion (5) regarding different default colors for text and math. My current version does meet this requirement. Can this be fixed?

@divenex see edits.

Thank you @Tom! Great idea using \NewDocumentCommand. Just a heads up: you can skip the optional square brackets when you're only passing the second optional parameter. For instance, $\hl(pink){x^2}+y^2$ changes the color in math mode. This tidies things up. You might want to update your answer accordingly.

There is only a remaining issue with your answer: now the function does not work without overlay specification: \hl{...} raises an error. You can fix it with \NewDocumentCommand{\hl}{D<>{1-}... instead of r<>.

@divenex See another edits.

Thank you so much. Your help has been invaluable. I've already integrated my \hl function with your modification into my workflow, and it's working perfectly.
