Beamer Color Issue Inside \colorbox with \setbeamercolor{math text}
When I set a default color for math in Beamer using \setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=green}, the surrounding color of math inside \colorbox{} is no longer respected; it reverts to the default Beamer color instead.
How can I fix this?
Here's a minimal example:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}  
 
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Before setting any default math color:
        
        \item $\textcolor{red}{a + \colorbox{yellow}{$b^2$} + c^3} + d^4$
        
        \setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=green}
        
        \item After setting \textcolor{green}{green} as the default math color:
        
        \item $\textcolor{red}{a + \colorbox{yellow}{$b^2$} + c^3} + d^4$
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}  

Here is the resulting output:

Note: I'm trying to resolve this behavior for use with my Universal TikZ highlighter for text, display/inline math, without jumps in Beamer overlays. However, the behavior is the same for \colorbox, so I simplified the question, assuming any solution will work for both.

With the $...$ inside your colorbox, you start a new inline math piece which will thus use math text colour.

Thanks @samcarter, so there is no easy way to make a function inherit the surrounding color instead? I assume this will require some changes to either an internal Beamer function, or a wrapper to \colorbox.

If you want to keep using the same colour, don't use constructs which force you to start a new math environment.

Unlike the situation with a \colorbox, you can assume that your custom math helper macro won't be used in different contexts. This means you could reset the math colour in your helper macro:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetheme{AnnArbor} 

\newcommand\xrectangle[2]{        
    [overlay, fill=#1, rounded corners, blend mode=multiply] 
    ($(#2.south west) - (.3em, .3em)$) rectangle ($(#2.north east) + (.3em, .3em)$);}

\newcommand\xmhl[3]{
  \setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=}
  \tikz[baseline=(a.base), inner sep=0]
        \node (a) {$#2#3$} \xrectangle{#1}{a}}
                
\newcommand\xhl[3]{%
    \ifmmode\mathpalette{\xmhl{#2}}{#3}\else%
        \tikz[baseline=(a.base), inner sep=0]
            \node (a) {#3} \xrectangle{#1}{a}\fi}
 
% Make \hl overlay-aware     
\NewDocumentCommand{\hl}{D<>{1-} O{yellow} D(){green!30} m}{\begingroup\alt<#1>{\xhl{#2}{#3}{#4}}{#4}\endgroup}%

\begin{document}  
 
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $\mathcolor{red}{a + \hl<1->{b^2} + c^3} + d^4$
        
        \setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=green}
        
        \item $\mathcolor{red}{a + \hl<1->{b^2} + c^3} + d^4$ test
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}  



Absolutely brilliant, @samcarter! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help and for even applying your solution directly to my \hl function in the other question. I truly appreciate it.

You can avoid the problem by e.g. using the hf-tikz package to highlight your math. This way, you don't have to start a new inline math segment inside the box. Alternatively, you could use tikzmarks, tcolorbox or other packages designed to highlight math.
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[beamer,customcolors,norndcorners]{hf-tikz}
\hfsetfillcolor{yellow}
\hfsetbordercolor{yellow}

\begin{document}  
 
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $\mathcolor{red}{a + \tikzmarkin<1->{a1} b^2 \tikzmarkend{a1} + c^3} + d^4$
        
        \setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=green}
        
        \item $\mathcolor{red}{a + \tikzmarkin<1->{a1} b^2 \tikzmarkend{a1} + c^3} + d^4$ test
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}  



Thanks for the suggestion. However, hf-tikz requires too much manual tweaking, which isn't feasible for me with hundreds of slides containing dense display/inline math. I need a solution with minimal syntax that's fully automated. My full requirements are here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/731629/103431. My function comes close, except for this text color annoyance.

For your custom highlighting command, you could reset the mathcolour in your math function to \setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=.}
